# create dynamic sitemap.xml in reactjs by every request in http://example.com/sitemap.xml

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sitemap, xml-sitemap

I have an SPA (reactjs) site that has some link like `http://example.com/blog/:id`
and I want to dynamically create a dynamic sitemap.

I know that an npm package like `react-router-sitemap` can generate a sitemap with a command but I want to create `sitemap.xml` every time that this URL gets visited: `http://example.com/sitemap.xml`. That way if I create a new blog post, I don't need to re-create the sitemap again.

How should I do this?

Comment: Generating a sitemap can put real strain on your database depending on how many URLs you have on your site.   It may take minutes or more to generate it.   It usually isn't advisable to generate them on the fly because it will take too long and slow down your site.   You usually want to re-generate them on a schedule.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a `cron-job` to achieve this. Load the blog ids you need and write to the `sitemap.xml` in the build folder.

Try like below. You need few packages installed; `node-cron`, `sitemap` and `axios`.

I have set up a simple express server to server-rendering react UIs and I call `startSiteMapGeneratorJob` function from there. This is working fine for me.

SiteMapGenerator.js

```
import cron from "node-cron";
import { SitemapStream, streamToPromise } from "sitemap";
import { Readable } from "stream";
import fs from "fs";
import axios from "axios";
import { BACKEND_API_URL } from "../constants/APIConstants";

const startSiteMapGeneratorJob = () => {
    generateBlogSitemap();
    console.log("site map job started");
    cron.schedule("* * 12 * *", function() {
        console.log("Running a task every 12 hours (twice a day)");
        generateBlogSitemap();
    });
};

export const generateBlogSitemap = async () => {
    try{
        const res = await axios.get(`${BACKEND_API_URL}/blog/getAllIDs`);

        const { success, blogIDs = [] } = res.data;
    
        if (success && blogIDs.length > 0) {
            // An array with the links
            const links = blogIDs.map(({ _id }) => {
                return { url: `/blog/${_id}` };
            });
    
            // Create a stream to write to
            const stream = new SitemapStream({ hostname: "https://example.com" });
    
            // Return a promise that resolves with your XML string
            const data = await streamToPromise(Readable.from(links).pipe(stream));
    
            fs.writeFileSync("./build/sitemap.xml", data.toString());
            console.log("Blog Sitemap Generated");
        } else {
            console.log("No Blog Sitemap Generated");
        }
    } catch(error){
        console.log("Sitemap generator error", error)
    }
};

export default startSiteMapGeneratorJob;
```

Comment: @mohammad mohammadi nodhe, check this out!!

Comment: thanks but unfortunately i'm not allowed to create cornjob